# add a column from one table to another in a specific place

Tags: linux, awk, paste

I have one table, separated by tabs, and one column that I created from another file. The tables look like this:

Table 1:

```
col1 col2 col3
 ch   NA   3
 ch   NA   4
 ch   NA   5
```

Table 2:

```
colX
 AA
 AA
 AA
```

Desired output:

```
col1 colX col2 col3
 ch   AA   NA   3
 ch   AA   NA   4
 ch   AA   NA   5
```

I know that ***paste*** could add the column to the end or the beginning of my table, but, How I could add the column in any position of the other table that I want? I would like to use bash commands instead of R because the files are huge and I don't want to upload them to R.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;next} {$1=$1 OFS a[FNR]} 1' table2 table1
```

Output will be as follows.

```
col1 colX col2 col3
ch  AA NA 3
ch  AA NA 4
ch  AA NA 5
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation too now.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{           ##FNR==NR is condition which will be TRUE when first Input_file named table2 is being read.
  a[FNR]=$0        ##Creating an array named a wohse index is FNR and value is current line value.
  next             ##next will skip all following statements which be ONLY read when 2nd Input_file named table1 is being read.
}
{
  $1=$1 OFS a[FNR] ##Re-creating first field where it concatenates its own value with array a value whose index is FNR.
}
1                  ##mentioning 1 will print edited or non-edited value of current line of table1 Input_file.
' table2 table1    ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: It is working, thank you very much. Could you explain to me how this is working, please?

Comment: @EricGonzález, sure added it now too.